# React navigation back to initial screen in stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have tabbat stack.

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={tabBar} initialRouteName={TABS.FIRST}>
  <Tab.Screen name={TABS.FIRST} component={FirstStackNavigator} />
  <Tab.Screen name={TABS.SECOND} component={SecondStackNavigator} />
  <Tab.Screen name={TABS.THIRD} component={ThirdStackNavigator} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I also a stack for each screen.

```
  <ThirdStack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName={ROUTES.PROFILE}>
    <ThirdStack.Screen name={ROUTES.PROFILE} component={Profile} />
    <ThirdStack.Screen name={ROUTES.SETTINGS} component={Settings} />
    <ThirdStack.Screen name={ROUTES.RESULT} component={Result} />
  </ThirdStack.Navigator>
```

I go from the `SECOND stack`, to the `SETTINGS screen in THIRD stack` and in the `Settings component` I have a `CLOSE` button, by clicking on which I want to return to the `first screen` of my current `PROFILE stack`. I've tried options with goBack(), popToTop() ..., but nothing seems to work. I either go back to the first tab in `FIRST stack` or the previous stack.

Comment: Are you able to navigate with 'useNavigation' hook? i.e. 'navigate(ROUTES.PROFILE);'

Comment: can you please share your whole navigation flow? so, i can try to help you.

Comment: The rest does not matter, it only complicates understanding.

Comment: Hey, Can you generate a snack demo I will help you? Seems like you need to use the reset method.